# AngularJS - Have a non-repeatable element within ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

This question is a little hard to explain so i will try with my actual code to show the example. I am using ng-repeat using the syntax "ng-repeat='a in **achievements** = ( | achievements entity is not defined until within the ng-repeat that is not an option. i am forced to place it AFTER the ng-repeat has ended.  Is there a different way to accomplish this, to be able to reference the filtered contents of the object before or within the ng-repeat (but without having it actually repeated)

```
            <div style="padding:10px;margin-bottom:10px;" ng-repeat="a in achievments =(userAchievementConfig.achievements 
                                                                    | filter:userAchievementConfig.filters.search 
                                                                    | filter:{UserTeam:userAchievementConfig.filters.team}
                                                                    | filter:{UserDept:userAchievementConfig.filters.dept})"
                                                    ng-if="$index >= userAchievementConfig.startNum && $index <= userAchievementConfig.endNum">
            <div ng-if="achievements.length == 0" class="alert alert-info text-center">No users match your current filter</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img ng-if="a.picture" data-ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{a.picture}}" border=0 class='img-rounded pull-left' style="max-height:125px;max-width:100%;" >
                <div ng-if="!a.picture" style="height:125px;width:100%;padding:3px;background-color:#CCC;"></div> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <h4 ng-bind="a.UserName"></h4>
                <span ng-bind="a.sComments"></span>
                <br><i> - <span ng-bind="a.RequestedByName"></span> in <span ng-bind="a.timeSubmitted"></span></i>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" ng-if="!userAchievementConfig.filters.search">
            <ul uib-pagination total-items="userAchievementConfig.achievements.length"  boundary-link-numbers="true" max-size="3" ng-model="userAchievementConfig.pageNum" class="pagination-sm nomargin" items-per-page="userAchievementConfig.itemsPerPage"></ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" ng-if="!userAchievementConfig.filters.search">
            Showing {{userAchievementConfig.startNum+1}} - {{userAchievementConfig.endNum+1}} of {{userAchievementConfig.achievements.length}} achievements
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Comment: it's still not really clear what you are trying to accomplish, or what your issue is here.

Comment: I want to move pagination before the ng-repeat, but still be able to reference the filtered list. But that filtered list doesn't exist until the ng-repeat is started

Comment: you could use `ng-repeat` with an alias, eg. `ng-repeat = a in userAchievementConfig.achievements | allYourFilters as achievements`, which would make `achievements` a `$scope` property.

Comment: I should have figured this out before .. i didn't make the connection that the alias was within the scope of the ng-repeat (since i can reference it outside and after the ng-repeat).   i was unable to refer to it BEFORE the ng-repeat as $scope.achievements, but as you said once i made it part of an object, like ng-repeat = a in $scope.userAchievementsConfig.filteredachievements = (<source> | <filters>) then it started working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get filtered item without ng-repeat as below code

```
$scope.filteredItems = $scope.$eval("userAchievementConfig.achievements  | filter:userAchievementConfig.filters.search | filter:{UserTeam:userAchievementConfig.filters.team}| filter:{UserDept:userAchievementConfig.filters.dept}");
```

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of doing it this way

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it resolves your issue so that others can get benefits

Comment: I will test it and mark as answer if it works for my case